# Asset sync uploading (almost) all assets to S3 on every deploy, even though nothing has changed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3, asset-pipeline

Some assets  are kept, but a lot of assets are uploaded every time (amonst others the tiny_mce files, but also static image files) even though I have changed nothing.

I am using Heroku on cedar stack, and v.0.5.4 of the asset sync gem.

Part of the log from Heroku push:

```
Uploading: assets/logo_na.png
Uploading: assets/icons/woofunction-icons/home_32.png
```

(Which have not been changed)

```
Ignoring: assets/application-2b6fe7367c39811f8bae3c83bd39e8bf.js.gz
Ignoring: assets/application-44fd5226ff0852aeecfcda68b9aa755c.css.gz
```

(These have not been changed either, but are properly ignored.)

This used to work just fine, the problem appeared after i moved the apps to the heroku europe stack.  I have also added the turbo-sprockets-rails3 (0.3.6) gem without any apparent difference in what is uploaded.

Comment: can you put your production.rb and application.rb file details
check if you set this:
`config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` in production.rb

Comment: Have you changed the S3 region too? See [this option](https://github.com/rumblelabs/asset_sync#amazon-s3-multiple-region-support)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try updating the asset_sync gem to the latest version. You are currently running 0.5.4 while the head version is 1.0.0 which is probably using an updated version of fog.

Asset syncing with asset_sync/fog has been quite problematic some time ago, I once run with [a similar issue: "Sync to S3 always copies all files"](https://github.com/karlfreeman/middleman-sync/issues/21) using the middleman_sync gem which relies on asset_sync.